# VS 2015 & Angular2 RC Typescript Virtual Project error

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to get the Angular 2 RC up and running in a Visual Studio 2015 project I have and I am getting the "@angular/core" module not found from a file in my Typescript Virtual Project. Everything is fine in the actual project.

I am thinking maybe the virtual project needs to be recompiled or something? I really don't understand Virtual Projects all that much.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone is interested - the issue was eventually resolved by a variety of making sure the correct version of TypeScript was being referenced, by closing and reopening Visual Studio (to refresh the virtual projects) and making sure the settings in the tsconfig file were correct.

Feel free to reach out if you have any questions

EDIT: To answer question in comments @Richard Nalezynski:

My tsconfig.json now looks as the following:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

If you have questions about any specific line items, let me know.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what settings in tsconfig were necessary?